# MySQL get data by calculated result

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have a table with 10000 rows and 2 columns of INTegers (`id,start_timestamp,speed_qty_per_second`).

When do MySQL SELECT, I need to calculate results from selected values. 
i do calculation:

```
$duration_time = time() - $start_timestamp; 
$actual_qty = $duration_time * $speed_qty_per_second;
```

I need to select data from table `WHERE $actual_qty > 100`.
This data will be accessed by a lot of users on fronted often, like onetime per sec for each user.

What is the **best approach**, to store cached data?

- MEMORY MySQL table?
- File (csv,XML)?

Comment: Timestamp stored as an integer? Beware, [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) is coming.

Comment: Could you add detail on what frontend? If it is a web app, memcached and controlling the granularity of when to accept a change in time() (say once per second pass a live query through to the backend) might work, or one could push on sql level the condition > 100 on the calculated quantity (aggregate) into a having clause, or instead of using csv/xml backends push sqlite database which you can also query via sql. Please some more details, as a **best** approach will depend on that. There is no global best solution, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a sql solution could be useful

```
 select 
   id,
   start_timestamp,
   speed_qty_per_second, 
   timediff(now(),start_timestamp)),
   timediff(now(),start_timestamp))* peed_qty_per_second
 from your_table
```

Comment: this is the most simple example, my formula is much more complicated to count http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1796884/341708

Comment: well the suggestion is when you can perform calculation in query do it.. and i can't image nothings different respect what you post ..